# Sails Project is Not Working

Tags: node.js, sails.js, sails-mongo

Sails project is not working. After `sails lift` command from terminal. I did run the project through the `localhost: 1337` port from browser. But its not loading, browser screen is blank. And there is no error message in terminal.

Note: The same project had run very well before few hours in same machine

Comment: Please add the `sails lift` output to your question. What about launching `sails lift --verbose`?

Comment: Is the page loading indefinitely? Does it happen on all pages?

Comment: No its not 'loading indefinitely', and it does not show any error message